# Insert data to two table with primary and foreign key

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I tried to find solution for my problem on other questions, but I couldn't. Maybe my problem is in the database tables. I made an application that connects to a Firebird database, and I try to insert data into two tables. One of them is like this:

| Id | Name | AddressId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | NameOfCustomer | 1 |

and second

| Id | Address | Default | CustomerId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Long Street 1, 88300 London | 1 | 2 |

I write insert in SQL like this:

```
EXECUTE BLOCK AS
declare variable id_customer bigint;
declare variable id_address bigint;
BEGIN
select gen_id(CUSTOMER_ID_GEN, 1) from rdb$database into :id_customer;
select gen_id(CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES_ID_GEN, 1) from rdb$database into        :id_address;
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (Id, Name, AddressId) values (:id_customer, 'Name', :id_address);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_ADDRESS (Id, Address, Default, CustomerId) values   (:id_address, 'Short Street 1', 1, :id_customer);
END
```

When I run code I have exception like this:

> violation of FOREIGN KEY constraint "CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ID_FK" on table
> "CUSTOMER"
> Foreign key reference target does not exist.

Maybe someone know how to write this SQL in Firebird without error? Should I disable foreign key for a while, and then try to insert data?

Below DLLs of two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(
  ID Integer NOT NULL,
  NAME STRING50_D NOT NULL,
  ADDRESS_ID Integer,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER ADD CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY (ADDRESS_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER_ADDRESS (ID) ON DELETE SET DEFAULT;

CREATE TABLE R3_CONTACT_ADDRESSES
(
  ID Integer NOT NULL,
  ADDRESS STRING200_D,
  DEFAULT BOOLEAN_D,
  CUSTOMER_ID Integer NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER_ADDRESS ADD CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_ADDR_CUSTOMER_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER (ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Please show the DDL of both tables. The error suggest that you have defined a foreign key constraint in CUSTOMER to CUSTOMER_ADDRESS, instead of in CUSTOMER_ADDRESS to CUSTOMER.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition has a cyclic dependency, because `CUSTOMER` has a foreign key to `CUSTOMER_ADDRESS`, and `CUSTOMER_ADDRESS` has a foreign key to `CUSTOMER`. Constraints in Firebird are not deferred until commit, but checked immediately. As a result, you cannot insert `CUSTOMER` because the referenced address does not exist yet, and you cannot insert `CUSTOMER_ADDRESS` first either, because then the customer does not exist yet.

To fix this, you need to take one of the following approaches

1. Insert `CUSTOMER` with `ADDRESS_ID` set to `NULL` (or leave it out of the insert), and update `CUSTOMER` to set `ADDRESS_ID` after you inserted the record into `ADDRESS_ID`.
2. If a customer has a single address, then put the address information in `CUSTOMER` and drop `CUSTOMER_ADDRESS`.
3. Remove `ADDRESS_ID` from `CUSTOMER`, and rely on `CUSTOMER_ID` in `CUSTOMER_ADDRESS` to link the records.
4. Remove `CUSTOMER_ID` from `CUSTOMER_ADDRESS`, and rely in `ADDRESS_ID` in `CUSTOMER` to link the records. With this approach you need to insert `CUSTOMER_ADDRESS` first. If this works for you, then taking approach 2 might be the better choice.

Comment: Avoiding "wide" tables might have its own merit, for high-load applications for example. If heavy selects on `customer` are frequent and reading address is rare, then offloading address into a separate aux-data table might have sense even for 1:1 correlation.  I mean, your option 2 is not universal advice, though it is often true.

Comment: Thanks for help. I didn't notice that the address_id field could be null, so this is actually the solution to my problem. All the time I thought that the addres_id field couldn`t be null.